# Java Date() is auto correcting the date we type in an input text field

Tags: java, date, spring-mvc

I have a Spring mvc form with input text field. I map that field with a java Date object. When I type the date wrong (For example **34/01/1985**), in the backend it is auto correct the date and give it as **03/02/1985** (03 Feb 1985). I want to stop this auto correction to validate the in the backend.

Folks, give me a solution?

**Update :**

```
<form:input path="person.dateOfBirth" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"/> 

public class Person  implements Cloneable{

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }
    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
}

public void  post( 
            PortletSession session,
            ActionRequest request,
            ActionResponse response, 
            @ModelAttribute("form") Form form,
            BindingResult errors,
            ModelMap mm) throws Exception {

print(form.getPerson().getDateOfBirth());

}
```

Comment: Use string instead of date and parse it yourself (with 'lenient' turned off).

Comment: Is there any workaround for java util Date? Can't we implement it with java util Date?

Comment: No. `java.util.Date` unable to store values like " 34/01/1985". It have one variable inside - count of millisecond since 1 Jan 1980.

Comment: :( All the db field mapping has been done for Date(). Okay, anyway if you find a workaround for this, let us know.

Comment: Workaraund is simple. Use different classes for db and rest services.

Comment: FYI, the old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATE; AJAX CALL]
Just use spring's `@DateTimeFormat` annotation and specify your `pattern`.

```
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
class Form {
    ...
    private static final String DATE_PATTERN = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = DATE_PATTERN)
    private Date yourDate;
    ...
 }
```

Make sure your `Spring MVC Controller` does validate your form:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path")
@ResponseBody
public final boolean validateFormOnSever(@Valid @ModelAttribute("yourForm") final Form form,
                 final BindingResult bindingResult, final Model model) {
   return bindingResult.hasErrors();
}
```

Now when you receive false (or a JSON Object like this {filed, hasError}) you display the message you want.

Comment: I already tried the same thing you showed here. But it is still auto correct the date we wrongly type. To validate the Date how can I get the actual value a person type?

Comment: Have you annotated your form in your Controller with @Valid annotation?

Comment: Actually, I am validating the date in an ajax call. There i get the auto corrected value. Is there any way we can find the Spring type mismatch without annotating the model attribute as @valid?

Comment: @nasminspy, I've updated my answer

Comment: Okay thanks. Will try and let you know.

Comment: Okay kindly let me know if it works

Answer (score 1):

In the front end use input type as date. HTML5 five this feature and with this the user only can choose the valid date and it seems cool. Just apply and see results :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `setLenient(false)`.

For reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29

Comment: It will be hard. Because framework do all the mapping. It is to late to do something when custom code receive date.